# I want to select of sums of amount against specific date and group by some description

Tags: sql-server, date, select, where-clause

My query is

```
SELECT SUM([CurrentAmount]) AS SUMS, Description 
FROM [PR_ABT] 
WHERE CheckDate = 12/27/2019   
GROUP BY Description
```

I am getting the following error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date as string literal **must be** in single quotes! And preferably, use the ISO-8601 format `YYYYMMDD` which is language independent - so try:

```
SELECT SUM([CurrentAmount]) AS SUMS, Description 
FROM [PR_ABT] 
WHERE CheckDate = '20191227' 
GROUP BY Description
```

Comment: i want ot pivot result and save them in temp table                                                   **           my SQL query is** 
SELECT SUM([CurrentAmount]) AS Sums, Description 
FROM [xyz] 
WHERE CheckDate = '20191129' 
GROUP BY Description


it results like 

sums: description
122    abc
233    xyz

    enter code here

but i want 

description abc xyz lmn abk nkf ...
sums        122 233 111 222 111

Comment: @AhsanUlHaq: that's a whole new question - please ask it separately